# How can I echo PHP error_log() statements to the output buffer

Tags: php, phpunit, echo, phpstorm, error-log

I use [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) to develop a PHP web application and use its built in PHPUnit test runner. In the output window within the IDE it shows the output buffer (e.g. anything that has been echoed).

I can see errors show up by using `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. However anything output using `error_log()` doesn't show up (but it does in the error log).

Is there a way I can get anything written to the error log to also show up in the output buffer?

Comment: Note: i'd be up for somehow keeping track of of where the error log file started and then outputting anything new written.

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough: wrap the function.

```
function error_log_out($message, $message_type=0, $destination=0, $extra_headers="") {
    error_log($message,$message_type,$destination,$extra_headers);
    echo $message; // optionally add some formatting
}
```

Comment: I don't want to introduce a new function. I realize our logging is sub optimal as we are leveraging error_log instead of a library; trying to work around that now.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, it's in theory possible to "hook" into the function by renaming the `error_log` function to something else and then wrapping the function as in my answer but with the original name. But that's major hax with a debugging extension and is all kinds of wrong!

Comment: Yeah not looking to do that

Answer (score 1):

I found that calling `php` with an ini `error_log` value of a file I did not have permission to write to; php would sent `error_log()` output to stdout then.

```
$ touch ~/my_php_error.log
$ php -d error_log=~/my_php_error.log -r 'error_log("Hello World");'
# Writes to ~/my_php_error.log

$ chmod -w ~/my_php_error.log
$ php -d error_log=~/my_php_error.log -r 'error_log("Hello World");'
Hello World
# Writes to stdout
```

`-r "...cmd"` can be substituted for a php file to run as well